# Is there a simple incision that would render a man impotent?

Tags: human-biology, surgery

I’m writing a novel in which two women (one of whom is a doctor) take revenge on a rapist by performing surgery on him.

What would be the simplest but most effective way of causing permanent and total erectile dysfunction?

I assume cutting one or more nerves but there are several up for contention:

The Dorsal nerve
Pudendal nerve
Inferior rectal nerve
Perineal nerve
Posterior scrotal nerves

Ideally, I’d like the surgery to be so minimally invasive that he wouldn’t even be aware that it had been done to him.

Comment: Snake Bite. There is a cobra in Thailand/Asia whose venom interferes with the male pituitary or some deep brain hormone regulation, and the result of enough venom is that he stops growing a beard, his testosterone drops, and he becomes like a 8 year old boy again.

Comment: @com.prehensible Thanks! My novel is set in a small English village so getting cobra venom may be a bit difficult, but I may use that for a future novel! Out of interest, why would a question like this get voted down with no explanation as to why? Have I not phrased it correctly? Thanks!

Comment: I think the downvotes are from people who might not think this stack is most appropriate for your question. I see the biological relevance, but future questions like these might be better answered in the medicalsciences stack or the writing stack.

Comment: Thanks Bruce. On the writing stack we generally migrate questions and explain why rather than just downvote them. But they're a cheery bunch over there. Glad I made the mistake of picking this stack, if I hadn't, I wouldn't have found you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's better suited for health.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You want to somehow damage the [cavernous nerves of the penis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavernous_nerves). If you damage the preganglionic root of the cavernous nerves (the pelvic splanchnic nerve), you'll create all kinds of other problems.

#### You might also  consider using a chemical agent instead of surgery; this will allow for increased discretion and ease of administration. I discuss this after the break in my answer.

Erection is driven by the parasympathetic nervous system; ejaculation is driven by the sympathetic nervous system. Since you're looking for "permanent and total erectile dysfunction," you want to disrupt parasympathetic innervation to the penis. The candidates you've mentioned (dorsal nerve, pudendal nerve, inferior rectal nerve, perineal nerve, posterior scrotal nerves) won't work since none of them provide parasympathetic innervation to the penis. Rather, the [dorsal nerve of the penis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorsal_nerve_of_the_penis) is a branch of the pudendal nerve and provides sympathetic (ejaculation) and sensory innervation; the inferior rectal nerves are also branches of the pudendal nerve and provide purely somatic innervation to the anus (these lie below the pectinate line, which marks the boundary we use to define internal and external hemorrhoids); the posterior scrotal nerves are a sensory branch of the perineal nerve, which itself is a branch of the pudendal nerve. [This plate from Gray's will help you visualize these relationships.](https://www.bartleby.com/107/Images/large/image837.gif)

> **["The Epidemiology and Pathophysiology of Erectile Dysfunction." Melman *et al. The Journal of Urology.* 1999.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022534701620457)**
>
> Erectile  dysfunction
> is
> a
> common
> condition  associated
> with  aging,
> chronic
> illnesses
> and
> various
> modifiable
> risk
> factors. Normal penile erection
> is a hemodynamic
> process
> that
> is
> dependent
> on
> corporal  smooth
> muscle relaxation mediated
> by
> parasympathetic neurotransmission, nitric
> oxide,
> and
> possibly
> other
> regulatory factors
> and
> electrophysiological
> events.
> As
> more
> knowledge
> is
> gained
> of
> the
> physiology
> and
> regulatory factors
> that
> mediate
> normal
> erectile
> function,
> the
> mechanisms
> involved
> in
> the
> pathophysiology
> of
> erectile
> dysfunction
> should
> be
> further
> elucidated.

So, let's say you want to go after the parasympathetic nerves to the penis – the cavernous nerves. These are postganglionic, meaning they've already synapsed in the cell bodies of their target organ. Here's another plate from Gray's to make clear the parasympathetic (blue) vs. sympathetic (red) innervation in the body:

[image: Autonomic Innervation]

As you can see, the preganglionic pelvic splanchnic nerve might be an easier target than the postganglionic cavernous nerves, which will be running all over the tissue of the penis, making them difficult to quickly and directly target. However, you risk disrupting other hindgut functions as you move closer to the sacral spine.

> **["The actions of parasympathetic and sympathetic nerves in human micturition, erection and seminal emission, and their restoration in paraplegic patients by implanted electrical stimulators." Brindley. *The Royal Society.* 1988.](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/235/1279/111.short)**
>
> Appropriate stimulation of the S2 roots causes the erectile tissue of the penis to swell... Implants that stimulate the S2, S3, and S4 anterior roots improve micturition, defaecation, and penile erection in many patients with spinal-cord injuries.

Your desired discretion will go out the window if your antagonist wakes up unable to normally urinate or defecate, so you might target the prostatic plexus, where the branches of the cavernous nerves arise, but this is a relatively deep structure (bound within the prostatic sheath) that you won't be able to discretely injure. When scientists test cavernous nerve injuries, they use a variety of techniques, but none of them are particularly non-invasive:

> **["Functional Sequelae of Cavernous Nerve Injury in the Rat: Is There Model Dependency." Mullerad *et al. The Journal of Sexual Medicine.* 2006.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1743609515312741)**
>
> Nerve Manipulation Techniques
> (1)  Control  group  (C):  underwent  a  laparotomy
> only  to  control  for  the  effect  of  anesthesia.  The
> pelvic  organs  were  not  disturbed  and  thus  the
> result was no visualization of the CN. (2) Exposure
> group (E): laparotomy and dissection of the pros-
> tate to enable visualization of the CNs bilaterally
> without any direct CN manipulation. (3) Neurot-
> omy  (N):  the  CNs  were  transected  bilaterally,
> 5  mm  distal  from  the  ganglion,  with  as  much  of
> the overlying fascia preserved to allow approxima-
> tion  of  the  nerve  ends.  (4)  Bulldog  clamp  crush
> group  (B):  a  vascular  bulldog  clamp  (60  g/mm
> 2
> ,
> Fine Science Tools, USA) was applied to each CN,
> 5  mm  distal  to  the  ganglion.  It  was  applied  for
> 30  seconds,  removed  for  30  seconds,  and  then
> reapplied  for  a  further  30  seconds.  (5)  Hemostat
> crush group (H): an ultra fine hemostat (12.5 cm, nonserrated, Fine Science Tools) was applied with
> full  tip  closure  in  the  same  manner  as  for  the  B
> group.

Understanding the anatomy of the penis will help you decide how to proceed. I think you're on the right track with a neurovascular or nerve injury. ["The Physiology of Human Penile Erection"](http://annals.org/aim/article-abstract/686428/physiology-human-penile-erection) (Weiss, *Annals of Internal Medicine,* 1972) includes this great figure, where each labelled letter in the pathway relates to a specific site of erectile dysfunction-causing injury:

[image: Erectile dysfunction injury sites]

You're most focused on sites F, G, and H. Here, F is caused by long-term illness and G is caused by, once again, invasive surgery:

> **SITE  F** The  incidence  of  erectile  dysfunction  in  diabetes  mellitus   exceeds   that   in   diabetic   retinopathy   or   nephropathy.  In a random study  of 200  diabetic  men,    59%   were  impotent.   The  incidence  of  impotence  does  not  correlate  with  the  duration  of  the  diabetes,  the  severity  of  the  imbalance  in  carbohydrate  metabolism,  or  the  degree  of  diabetic  control.   Impotence   is   occasionally   the   initial   clinical   manifestation  of  diabetes,  and  diabetes  should  be  considered  as  a  possible  cause  whenever  a  man  complains  of  impotence.  Ellenberg   found  a high correlation between  neurogenic  bladder  abnormalities  and  impotence  and  thereby  postulated  that  an  autonomic   neuropathy   was  the  cause   of   impotence  in  diabetes  mellitus.  Other  causes  of  autonomic  neuropathies  are also frequently  associated with impotence. Simpson   speculated  that  a  diabetic  angiopathy  involving   the   small   vessels   of   the   erectile   tissues   might impede  the blood flow and lead to impotence in some  cases.   
> **SITE  G** Radical   surgical   procedures,   such  as  abdominoperineal  extirpation  of  the  rectum,  frequently  destroy  the  nerve  plexuses  from  both  spinal  erection  centers,  resulting   in   complete   impotence.   The   effects    of    sympathectomy  on  potency,  if  any,  have  been  discussed   earlier.   Other   surgical   procedures,   such   as   transurethral   prostate   resection,   that  do  not  interfere  with  the  neural  or  vascular  structures  mediating  erection   usually   do   not   alter   penile   potency. 
> **SITE  H** Drugs  that  inhibit  the  action  of  acetylcholine  on structures   innervated   by   postganglionic   autonomic   nerves  (for  example,  methantheline  bromide)  occasionally   cause  impotence.   This   effect   is  consistent  with  the  role  that  cholinergic  fibers  play  in  opening the polsters  and initiating erection.

---

#### Alternative method: chemical agent

Site H caught my attention most, since the author mentions inhibitory drugs causing impotence. This might be the non-invasive, discrete route you've wanted.

> **["Pharmacology of Penile Erection." Andersson. *Pharmacological Reviews.* 2001.](http://pharmrev.aspetjournals.org/content/53/3/417)**
>
> *Phosphodiesterase Inhibitors.* The L-arginine/NO/GC/cGMP pathway seems to be the most important for penile erection in some species (see above), and recent results with sildenafil, a selective inhibitor of the cGMP-specific PDE5, further support the view that this may be the case also in humans. Sildenafil is 4000 times more selective for PDE5 than for PDE3, 70 times more selective for PDE5 than PDE4, but only 10 times more selective for PDE5 than for PDE6. Sildenafil is rapidly absorbed after oral administration (bioavailability 41%) and has a plasma half-life of 3 to 5 h.

PDE5 degrades cGMP, which is required for an erection. PDE5 inhibitors (Viagra, Levitra, etc.) prevent cGMP degradation. You might have your protagonist culture PDE5-overexpressing cells and isolate the enzyme (or, she could buy a bunch from [Sigma](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/catalog/product/sigma/e9034?lang=en&region=US)) and sneakily inject the isolate into your villain. This probably wouldn't *really* work, but I think it might be a better (more plausible) fictional solution than a surgery, which you won't be able to cover up without some other kind of trauma to the area. (Plus, at that point, why not just use the cover-up trauma to create the erectile injury in the first place?)

Comment: Bruce, I had no idea erection was so complex! You’re an absolute star for giving up so much of your time, thank you. I should name one of the characters after you but since the only male character available is the rapist, I’m sure you’d prefer I didn’t!

Comment: There is a reason I’d like to use surgery: another character will train to be a nurse after assisting with this surgery.

So, if nerves aren’t an option, how about we target blood flow to cause vasculogenic erectile dysfunction?

I found an article on Laparoscopically assisted penile revascularization for vasculogenic impotence, so couldn’t she perform the same operation to cause instead of cure impotence? What if she were to sever either the inferior epigastric artery, the dorsal artery, or the interior pudendal artery?

Comment: Long story, but I got to watch a vasectomy and through two tiny incisions, he was able to pull out, cut and cauterise the vas deferens tubes. It would be great if she could do something similar with one of these arteries? Or, failing that, a small incision and cauterise the artery. But I have a feeling you’re going to tell me severing arteries isn’t as simple as severing the vas deferens?

Comment: You can definitely sever arteries quickly, but you’ll have two problems: (1) blood is going to want to go somewhere, so you’ll need to cauterize (like you saw with the accompanying vasculature on the vas defrens) or otherwise ligate those vessels; (2) blood is bringing oxygen to those tissues – if you deprive them of blood (to prevent an erection), you risk ischemic necrosis and subsequent amputation. To cause erectile instability, you’ll want to damage the deep artery of the penis, which supplies the corpus cavernosum (the erectile body). As the name suggests, it’s deep!

Comment: No need to thank me! If you think my answer was sufficient for your question, you can mark it “correct” and it’ll come off of SE’s unanswered board.

Comment: Have marked it!

Comment: Bruce, I found some diagrams, you’re right, it’s too deep, impractical. But, I also read that an erection is maintained because, “as the tunica stretches, it blocks off the veins that take blood away from the corpora cavernosa” (sounds like a Harry Potter spell). So, what if she were to stent either the circumflex vein or the deep dorsal vein (which despite its name appears to run along the top surface of the penis)? Would the stent prevent blood from staying in the penis while avoiding necrosis due to blood deprivation?

Comment: Obviously, this doesn’t need to be a 100% solution, as a surgeon, she could admit that she’s not sure it will work, nobody’s ever done this before, just as long as there’s a chance it could work. That’s really all you need for fiction!  Thanks!

Comment: That's very clever! Ensuring venous drainage is a great, discrete solution – you could place a stent by entering a different vessel (further down the leg, for example) to obscure your work even more (although this stretches realism a little since you'd need to pass through the prostatic venous plexus – easier to go in directly). [Venous stripping](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/315596201_Penile_venous_stripping_surgery_is_a_viable_option_for_erectile_dysfunction_after_unsuccessful_vascular_interventions) can treat ED – doing the opposite (stenting/shunting) should work!

Comment: BRILLIANT!!  I was hoping you'd say that! But I wouldn't have reached that solution if it wasn't for all your pointers. Going in through the leg would be awesome in terms of discretion, but looking at the diagrams, the deep dorsal vein runs along the top of the penis. I guess, if she does it up high enough where it's buried in his pubic hair, he won't notice the incision. And one of his colleagues will be slipping him pain killers for a few days. Excellent! One impotent rapist! All in a day's work! Thanks!